# Get Auth Token from headers before loading any components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am new to angular and working on modifying a code.

Currently the code works with default angular method of loading all components together, which means, multiple components are making http calls together.

My angular app is hosted on azure app service with azure ad authentication configured from azure portal.

from 1st point, i want to improve and ensure, that
First, before loading any component , I get id_token parameter from http://host/.auth/me url which will be my auth token.(This auth token as auth header will be used to make api calls to backend)

Once i have this auth token, i shall store it in local/session storage. Only when this process is complete, i want to proceed with loading of other angular components.

I have read about lazy loading of component. but I want to know what is the best practice to do above scenario.

Comment: You should try using some kind of AuthGuard. For example, why `loggedin$` in AuthGuard is false, then do not render component(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think we have 2 ideas of how you could handle visibility restriction for your components.

in our application we can handle our login and other authentification in our auth.service.ts.

```
// auth.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
private token: string;
private loggedIn = false;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


getLoggedIn() {
  return this.loggedIn;
}

login(email:string, password:string): Promise <string> {
  const promise = new Promise < string > ((resolve, reject) => {
    const authData = { email: email, password: password }
      this.http.post < { token: string } > (environment.backendUrl + '/api/user/login', authData).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
         const token = response.token;
         this.token = token;
         if (token) {
           this.loggedIn = true;
         }
}
```

as you can see in the above snippet once the login is succesfull we receive a token in our response body, which i assume is similiar to how you get a token in your application. then we assign this response.token to the token variable inside our auth.service.ts file. after the token is assigned to the variable inside the auth.service.ts file we can read it and check for a token by calling the getLoggedIn() function from anywhere in the application by importing the auth.service.ts file.

now back to how one can restrict visibility of components by checking for a token. one way is we can import our auth.service.ts file into the component where we want to restrict component visibility by adding it into the constructor like this

```
// .ts file where you want to restrict visibility
export class component {
loggedIn = false;

constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.loggedIn = this.authService.getLoggedIn();
}
```

you can see the component is checking for a token during the ngOnInit call. this means in our corresponding html file we can use this loggedIn variable with an *ngIf to restrict visibility of certain html elements or even the whole component if wanted

```
// .html file
<div *ngIf=loggedIn>
   <h1> title </h1>
   <p> here you be your text </p>
</div>
```

another way is to implement a guard as mikhail and gytis have mentioned before. this guard checks for a token before routing to the page to make sure only users who are logged in are able to visit certain pages. we can do this by adding an auth.guard.ts file like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable < boolean > | Promise < boolean > {
    const loggedIn = this.authService.getLoggedIn();
    if (!loggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return loggedIn;
  }

}
```

once we have added this file we can enable a tokencheck in our app-routing.ts file like this.

```
// app-routing.ts file
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: "home", component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: "login", component: LoginPageComponent },
    { path: "signup", component: SignupPageComponent },
    { path: "profile/:id", component: ProfilePageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

in the snipped the profile page is protected by the AuthGuard so only logged in users are able to visit this page. if a user is not logged in the AuthGuard redirects the user to the login page so even if manually typing in the url in a browser one still needs to log in before visiting the page.

i am also quite new to SO but i tried my best to write a clear answer for you hoping i could be of any help to you! :) have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are multiple ways to do that

**APP_INITIALIZER**

You can write an async function loading a token, and inject the function in the main module. No components will be initialized until the function's promise is resolved. This way is simple but ugly. Users will see a white screen while a token request is in progress.

```js
@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => () => {
        return fetch('https://token.provired.com/getToken')
          .then(x => x.json())
          .then(x => localStorage.setItem("token", x));
      },
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Root component**

You can initialize a token request from a root component, usually, it's `app.cpmponent.ts`. In the component's template, you can show some markup or a spinner while the request is in progress to let users know that the app is working. Other components` initialization is supposed to be blocked by `*ngIf`. Check the snippet below

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="!tokenLoaded">Please wait</div>
    <div *ngIf="tokenLoaded">
      <app-my-component></app-my-component>
    </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  tokenLoaded = false;

  ngOnInit(){
    getToken().then(token => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      tokenLoaded = true;
    })
  }
}
```

**Guard**

As @Gytis TG mentioned in the comments, you can run the token request in a guard. The advantage of this approach is that you will have a separate piece of code responsible for token loading.